# How to change the color of a text in a button, when the cursor touch the button?

Tags: wordpress

I have a problem with a specific button of my site. 
In the bottom of the site, there is a button with text "Click here to contact us".
When i touch the border of "Click here to contact us" button the color of the button become white and the text, stays white, as a result someone could not see the text. To appear the text (with purple color), i must touch with cursor the text.
My question is how to make the code, so when touch with cursor the button (the color of the button becomes white), to change automatically and the text "contact with us" (the color of text to become purple)?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On popup short code you can see similar like like this

```
[popup_trigger id="custom" custom_id="eee" tag="H5" classes="greet-text" do_default]
Click here to contact us![/popup_trigger]
```

remove tag="H2" & classes="greet-text"

It will look/Work like other pop up buttons.

Later you can adjust that button with div#contact-information selectors.